# Filter taxonomy term view by referenced taxonomy term

Tags: 7, views

Using two taxonomies.

Fruit:

`Banana
Orange
Blueberry
Strawberry
Lemon`

Fruit taxonomy has a term reference to the color taxonomy

Color:

`Red
Orange
Yellow
Blue
Purple
Green`

Created a view using the built in taxonomy term view in a content pane::

Fields
Taxonomy term: Fruit Color [this is excluded from display]

Taxonomy term: Name

Filter criteria
Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name (= Fruit)

Relationships
Taxonomy term: Content using Fruit

[Configure Relationship: Taxonomy term: Content using Fruit
Relate each Content with a Fruit set to the term.
Require this relationship]

View Output::

`Red
 Strawberry`

`Orange
 Orange`

`Yellow
 Banana
 Lemon`

`Blue
 Blueberry`

I would like to add a contextual filter to this view that takes the Color taxonomy name from the url and only shows the fruit for that color.

color/red would only show:

`Red
 Strawberry`

color/yellow would only show:

`Yellow
 Banana
 Lemon`

I'm stuck on how to add the contextual filter. I've tried taxonomy term name with validation set to change the term name to id. I also tried the fruit_color field with validation set to change the term name to id.

Should the term name/fruit_color field be configured differently? Do I need to add another relationship?

> Additional info: 
>   The view displays taxonomy terms. 
>   The result set is empty when I try adding a contextual filter. 
>   The relationship field should only show Fruit terms that have been used at least once to tag content.

Comment: Is the view you are using set to display content? Or taxonomy terms?

Comment: It is displaying taxonomy terms.

Comment: Sounds good, is the current problem an empty result set or what? Please update your question with this, it's important.

Comment: Another question: Do you need the relationship field to only show Fruit terms that have been used at least once to tag content? Or am I assuming too much?

Comment: I am following your setup/configuration, but cannot reproduce the problem. Does your View display results without the Contextual Filter? Do you have content tagged with Fruit at the moment? (ignore this last question if it is too obvious)

Comment: The view displays results without the contextual filter. I have the current result listed under 'View Output' in the question above. I am hoping to use a contextual filter to narrow the current results to one color based on the url.

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question: No, it shouldn't need to be configured differently; it should work the way you describe.
Here is a screenshot of my configuration (following your description) that works as you would expect (you can see the contextual filter in the background set to 'yellow'):

[image]

Perhaps you can spot some tiny deviation from your config here.
Good luck in any case!